# Read Time Out on Spring Boot

Tags: java, security, ssl, tls1.2

I am debugging a Read Time out issue in Spring Boot application. Surprisingly , the same code in other app on same machine is working. I cannot figure out if its issue with SSL handshake or application read.

Can anyone experienced in SSL give me a clue if its problem with SSL handshake or application?

```
*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
Signature Algorithm SHA256withRSA
Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 29542406192106943339474754606390399164782715617307032715472057145354950567400
  public y coord: 79571066831123360733094408216631886961080379522778654162313628092705655634054
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
http-nio-8080-exec-2, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 4
*** ServerHelloDone
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
ECDH Public value:  { 4, 9, 60, 230, 143, 12, 133, 160, 181, 201, 189, 200, 105, 7, 87, 100, 204, 181, 150, 182, 224, 126, 143, 197, 242, 190, 28, 207, 207, 134, 161, 202, 148, 213, 204, 168, 189, 107, 68, 115, 175, 56, 137, 133, 48, 120, 162, 168, 254, 239, 73, 93, 35, 67, 10, 87, 112, 156, 143, 169, 115, 176, 212, 41, 84 }
http-nio-8080-exec-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 70
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: B1 95 73 21 31 9C 64 04   4D 60 92 E4 D5 8F 1C A6  ..s!1.d.M`......
0010: FD 1A E9 3D 27 2E A5 DC   18 37 72 36 02 EC 54 98  ...='....7r6..T.
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 5F 37 D9 C2 BD 34 43 7E   AF 6F 03 04 96 2C 63 CE  _7...4C..o...,c.
0010: B3 11 D0 58 10 B2 3C 78   E6 8A 7B 4E E3 03 FA 7F  ...X..<x...N....
Server Nonce:
0000: 8E BC 68 EE 18 B4 42 FA   4E 27 17 2B B9 42 3E A8  ..h...B.N'.+.B>.
0010: BB 31 80 35 C1 7A 83 B3   44 4F 57 4E 47 52 44 01  .1.5.z..DOWNGRD.
Master Secret:
0000: 32 F6 E3 7E BC 84 D1 2E   15 8F 8C EB 48 DC F1 09  2...........H...
0010: A5 BB 43 EA F5 96 06 57   8E 3B 94 9B 61 A0 A3 88  ..C....W.;..a...
0020: B5 28 45 8C F2 D9 B3 B1   A6 99 49 95 1D D0 AB FE  .(E.......I.....
... no MAC keys used for this cipher
Client write key:
0000: E8 BC 4E FC 36 47 F6 0A   C8 59 18 C2 6B 21 02 46  ..N.6G...Y..k!.F
Server write key:
0000: 74 C0 13 2A FA 47 9E 92   B3 10 3E 44 8E D4 EA 6E  t..*.G....>D...n
Client write IV:
0000: 30 66 E6 DC                                        0f..
Server write IV:
0000: 26 21 4D F6                                        &!M.
http-nio-8080-exec-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 113, 74, 102, 42, 210, 89, 9, 19, 236, 155, 7, 215 }
***
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C 71 4A 66 2A   D2 59 09 13 EC 9B 07 D7  ....qJf*.Y......
http-nio-8080-exec-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
http-nio-8080-exec-2, handling exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to api.eu.mailjet.com:443 [api.eu.mailjet.com/35.187.79.8] failed: Read timed out
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.walmart.services.hermes.connectors.mailjet.config.TestController.run2(TestController.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 65 more
```

Answer (score 0):

If the same code is working from a different application running on same machine and that connecting to api.eu.mailjet.com at port 443 too then it will not be problem of firewall. Please compare connection timeout value on both the application and retry it by increasing timeout value.

Comment: Did but no luck.